# running multiple instances of ajax function - only second instance updates

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

I am having difficulty calling multiple instances of the same Ajax.Request function.  (I'm using the Prototype framework). Here is the function:

```
function send_SMS(id)
{
    status_id = 'status_link_' + id;

    new Ajax.Request('sendSMS.php', 
    {
        method:'post',
        parameters: {link_id: id},
        onCreate: function(){
            $(status_id).update("sending...");
        }, 
        onSuccess: function(transport){
            if (transport.responseJSON.success) {
                $(status_id).update("sent");
            } else {
                $(status_id).update("unable to send");
            }
        },
        onFailure: function(){ 
            $(status_id).update("unable to send");
        }       
    });
}
```

If I call this function twice with 2 different id numbers i.e.:

```
send_SMS("1");
send_SMS("2");
```

only the second ID is updated by the onSuccess function.  The sendSMS.php file is successfully run twice (as the name suggests it sends an SMS message and indeed the 2 messages are successfully sent), but the onSuccess function seems to only be called the second time.

Is the javascript confusing the 2 instances?

Comment: "but the onSuccess function seems to only be called the second time" -- put `alert(123);` there and count how much times it is called

Comment: my whole life and just until now discovered the word "second" can hold two meanings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because status_id is a global variable, and therefore enters in the context of your both calls within the callback where its reference is being called:

```
onSuccess: function(transport){
        if (transport.responseJSON.success) {
            $(status_id).update("sent");
        } else {
            $(status_id).update("unable to send");
        }
    }
```

The thing is, the onSuccess callback will **compile** when it is called, with its context at **that** moment. And at that moment, the status_id will be equal to "status_link_2", because most chance that your call to `send_SMS("2");` will come before the return of the first sms_send call.

A solution would be to:

- send the id within the ajax call, and retrieve it in the response to build your status_id variable, or
- use synchrone mode so the sms1 return comes back before the call of sms2.

Comment: Thanks for the response -- the problem was exactly as you mentioned with my variable scope. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @AndyB It would be much easier to just use a closure, so you wouldn't have to change anything except for the snippet you posted above. Never do anything synchronously unless that's the only option (which it won't ever be, believe me)

Answer (score 0):

This is the working function:

```
function send_SMS(id)
{
    new Ajax.Request('sendSMS.php', 
    {
        method:'post',
        parameters: {link_id: id},
        onCreate: function(){
            $('status_link_' + id).update("sending...");
        }, 
        onSuccess: function(transport){
            if (transport.responseJSON.success) {
                $('status_link_' + id).update("sent");
            } else {
                $('status_link_' + id).update("unable to send");
            }
        },
        onFailure: function(){ 
            $('status_link_' + id).update("unable to send");
        }       
    });
}
```